# Tick and Feature labels in Biopython

Tags: plot, biopython, dna-sequence

With the following minimal code

```
from Bio.Graphics import GenomeDiagram
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature, FeatureLocation

gdd = GenomeDiagram.Diagram('Construct Diagram')
construct_track = gdd.new_track(1, scale=True, scale_format="SInt", scale_smalltick_interval=10, scale_largetick_interval=100, scale_ticks=True, start=0, end=2222)
track_features = construct_track.new_set()

feature = SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(50,100, strand=+1))
track_features.add_feature(feature, name="my feature name", label=True, label_angle=30)

feature2 = SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(500,550, strand=-1))
track_features.add_feature(feature2, name="my feature name", label=True, label_angle=30)

gdd.draw(format="linear", fragments=1, start=0, end=2222)
gdd.write("test.png", "PNG")
```

I obtain the following (hideous) figure:

[image]

Now, the figure appearance can be tweaked to my satisfaction, with two notable exceptions:

- I cannot set the scale labels correctly (ntice how all major ticks between 1Kbp and 2 Kbp read just "1Kbp" - I would settle either for 1100 or 1.1Kbp)
- I cannot make the label of my second feature conform to how the first feature is labeled (currently the text is up-side-down, and if I change the angle to 210, it starts extending into rather than outward from the track (see next figure)

[image]

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of resources:

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Graphics.GenomeDiagram._Track.Track-class.html
http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html

It looks like there are at least a couple of options you can play around with:

**Tick labels**

> - I cannot set the scale labels correctly (ntice how all major ticks between 1Kbp and 2 Kbp read just "1Kbp" - I would settle either for
>     1100 or 1.1Kbp)

If you make `scale_format=None` in the call to `gdd.new_track()` (or just leave that argument out), you'll get 1100, etc.

**Feature labels**

> - I cannot make the label of my second feature conform to how the first feature is labeled (currently the text is up-side-down, and if I
>     change the angle to 210, it starts extending into rather than outward
>     from the track (see next figure)

You can try passing `label_position="end"` to `track_features.add_feature()`. If you combine this with an angle of 210, it will at least make it not extend outward from the track, though it will go up into the green shaded area. Perhaps this is acceptable for you.

---

Putting these two together in your example:

```py
from Bio.Graphics import GenomeDiagram
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature, FeatureLocation

gdd = GenomeDiagram.Diagram('Construct Diagram')
construct_track = gdd.new_track(1, scale=True, scale_format=None, scale_smalltick_interval=10, scale_largetick_interval=100, scale_ticks=True, start=0, end=2222)
track_features = construct_track.new_set()

feature = SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(50,100, strand=+1))
track_features.add_feature(feature, name="my feature name", label=True, label_angle=30)

feature2 = SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(500,550, strand=-1))
track_features.add_feature(feature2, name="my feature name", label=True, label_angle=210, label_position="end")

gdd.draw(format="linear", fragments=1, start=0, end=2222)
gdd.write("test.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: The latter of the two suggestions in sadly even worse than the current solution. Do you know how I could make it extend outwards from the track (meaning further downwards)? Also, if there is such a choice, I would prefer notations like 1.1Kbp for my scale rather than 1100. I read the docs, but none of this is particularly obvious.